# Why wouldn't a crime czar control drugs, but a pet cartel?

Tags: crime, criminal-underworld, pets

The year is 2058 of the Gregorian Calendar. The villain of my story is a crime czar. He does not want to control drugs: he prefers to rule a pet cartel.

The pets that are on the list of this cartel include: mice, rats, hamsters, gerbils, capybaras, guinea pigs, dogs, cats, pigs, iguanas, chameleons, bearded dragons, snakes, turtles, dwarf caimans, canaries, parrots, chickens, and ducks.

So, the question is: why would my crime czar control a pet cartel, and why would it be beneficial for him?

Comment: I feel like this applies: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/when-should-i-close-a-question-as-too-story-based
What problem are we attempting to help you solve? In order to be a "crime czar" (and not just a corporation dealing in pet sales), we must assume he deals in illegal pets (or illegal sales of legal pets), the pets are highly valuable, and that seems rather self-answering.

Comment: For why he wouldn't control a drug cartel, the simple solution would be that, by the time the story takes place, the sale, use, and distribution of drugs has been widely legalized and subject to regulations. There is simply no point for anyone to buy drugs from shady dealers that cut their supply with God-knows-what when people can buy them cheaply and readily with guarantees about quality and purity. An illegal cartel producing drugs simply can't compete with the amount of legal producers. This is, in fact, one of the many arguments for legalizing drugs in real life.

Comment: As for a pet cartel, I'm thinking that sales of all of these pets have been made illegal, but I am having a hard time thinking as for how and why such a situation would arise within 35 years, so I can't write an answer to the question.

Comment: Why are you asking a question about a character's motivations on a worldbuilding site? We're not here to write your characters for you.

Comment: @user73910 I'm sure at least some members of PETA would love to make pet ownership illegal.  Or aliens have uplifted all of the listed species to sapience and keeping one as a pet is considered slavery.  Or those species - led by the mice - were sapient all along and have come out as such now that Earth has finished being used to calculate the Ultimate Question.  OP is asking for brainstorming here, not just about one character but the entire world, so VTC.

Comment: I am from Brazil. Pet cartels are a thing there, and Monty Wild's answer is spot on why these things happen. Parrots are illegal to have as pets in my home country yet for some inane reason everybody wants one.

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as to why a criminal organization might exist to sell anything: it's illegal and popular.

Comment: I was the last close voter and I'd like to explain why. Per the [help/on-topic], we're here to build worlds, not tell stories. On that same page you'll read, "If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." The problem is that there will be many reasons (from, "I just like animals better" to "they're more profitable" to "there's a bigger adrenaline rush" to "it's easier to confess at church..." etc.) and there's no right answer (all answers have equal value), which is prohibited in [help/dont-ask].

Comment: This sounds more like a story-based question to me. It could be reframed to be a worldbuilding question though. Make it about the island in general and not about the motivations of one specific character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trade in endangered species is something like second or third in illegal trade - behind drugs - people pay a lot for animals, or parts of them

But! Your crime czar deals with pets. I'd suggest that we're dealing with designer animals - heavily genetically modified. We can make dragon like lizards, super fancy looking ducks, etc.

We know that companies can patent and licence out GM organisms, with restrictions on breeding them - see Monsanto and GM crops.

Your Czar is simply engaging in large scale piracy - they grow up rip off versions of all the most popular breeds, and sell them. You might see wide scale animal theft to aquire these breeds, you might see a load of smuggling to move them around

As to why people want them? A legitimate designer animal can cost tens of thousands. His cartel will get you one for a fraction of that.

Answer (score 5):

For a crime cartel to exist, the sale of the goods in which they trade must be either illegal or restricted, and in high demand.

We have learned this from prohibition of alcohol in the USA in the 1920s and early 1930s: Restricting access to a desirable product will lead to criminal organisations who supply the product at inflated prices, for profit.  When a product is in low supply and high demand, those providing the product can increase their prices to whatever the market will bear.

So, for a pet cartel to exist, the pets in which they deal must be restricted or illegal.  This is not beyond the bounds of possibility.  For example, ferrets are illegal in a small number of states in Australia and the US.  For a pet cartel to exist, the laws restricting pet ownership or trade must be much more restrictive and unpopular... perhaps it has become illegal to own, breed and/or trade common pets such as cats or dogs, let alone less common pets like ferrets.

I can't imagine *why* a government might want to outlaw pet ownership... but [it has been done](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-62205744) in Iran.  No doubt there are now Iranian pet smugglers...

As to why not drugs?  Perhaps the government just doesn't care about them.  If drugs are in common supply, no matter how addictive or harmful, there's no profit in smuggling them.

Comment: Great point about Iran. Also brings to mind the cartel actually funding all the PETA groups they can find, and trying to radicalize them. "Free the animals! Ban pet stores!" All playing into the pet cartel's hands...

Answer (score 4):

Just about *any* cartel can produce profits if it distorts markets. The pet cartel does not move illegal goods, it moves legal goods in an illegal, anti-competitive, **hard to prove** manner. Would you rather deal with the [Antitrust Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Justice_Antitrust_Division) of the DOJ, or with the [Drug Enforcement Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_Enforcement_Administration)?